# PHPUnit not returning to next test case

Tags: phpunit

I have two test cases, one returns a value, the next is *supposed* to use the return value.

```
class GenerateAckFeedTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testThankyouAckFeedErrors() 
    {
        $ackFeed = array(1,2,3);
        return $ackFeed;
    }

    /***
     * @depends testCitiThankyouAckFeedErrors
     */
    public function testCitiThankyouAckFeedGeneration(array $ackFeed)
    {

    }
}
```

The error I get is:
There was 1 error:

1) testCitiThankyouAckFeedGeneration(GenerateAckFeedTest)
Exception: 
ERRNO: 4096 
TEXT: Argument 1 passed to GenerateAckFeedTest::testCitiThankyouAckFeedGeneration() must be an array, none given 
LOCATION: /home/pvarney/host-server/www/active/unit_tests/GenerateAckFeedTest.php, line 131, at November 15, 2010, 10:55 am
Showing backtrace:
GenerateAckFeedTest.testCitiThankyouAckFeedGeneration() # line    0, file: unknown
ReflectionMethod.invoke(Object:GenerateAckFeedTest) # line  489, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.runTest() # line  404, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.runBare() # line  607, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php
PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult.run(Object:GenerateAckFeedTest) # line  375, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php
PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.run(Object:PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult) # line  677, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php
PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite.runTest(Object:GenerateAckFeedTest, Object:PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult) # line  658, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php
PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite.run(Object:PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult, false, Array[0], Array[0]) # line  324, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php
PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner.doRun(Object:PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite, Array[4]) # line  128, file: /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php
PHPUnit_TextUI_Command.main() # line   52, file: /usr/bin/phpunit

I feel like I'm missing something fairly obvious.

Comment: What PHPUnit version are you using?

Comment: Can you provide a running example ? Maybe that will spawn some answers

Comment: I'm using phpunit 3.3.16. (Sorry for the late response, weekend came).  I'll edit my example for a running example.  Thanks a million, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to PHPUnit/Util/Test.php getDependencies() method signature test dependencies were implemented in PHPUnit 3.4.0.

You were using 3.3.16 - an older version which does not support this.

Answer (score 6):

There were two issues, one I believe was the version (I would have accepted Anti's answer, but it was a comment), the other was the number of stars I was using in the comment.

I had

```
/***
 *
 */
```

I needed

```
/**
 *
 */
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out yourself. I also added an answer, hopefully useful for someone else in the future.